# Create new control files using SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

down vote
favorite

I need help with creating controlfile using sqlplus. I have used next steps, I altered spfile, shutdown database, startup nomount, used next command to create controlfile but it failed:
    create controlfile
    set database orcl
    logfile controlnew1
    ('\oracle\oradata\orcl\controlnew1.log’,
    '\oracle\oradata\orcl\controlnew1.log’)
    resetlogs;
My specifications is to create 2 new controlfiles named contronew1 and controlnew2 in location CONTROL01. I have found related article in oracle documentation but aberrantly I don't understand. I would be thankful for any help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are practicing backup and recovery. The best way to do this is to do the following:

```
ALTER DATABASE BACKUPUP CONTROLFILE TO TRACE;
```

This will create a trace file under the diag directory, assuming that you are at least running 11g. You can open the file with notepad and there are two sets of instructions for creating the control file. One for using archive log and one for not using archive log. You should take a look at the file and see what is included. You can use this for moving the database or any of its components. Here are some links that you should look at.

[CREATE CONTROLFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5003.htm)

[DATABASE CONCEPTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/CNCPT/title.htm)

Comment: Your very welcome